# Could I Extend Facebook Access_Token Expiration Time without Single Sign-On?

Tags: iphone, authorization, facebook-access-token, facebook-ios-sdk

I am a newbie on integrating facebook to iphone.
Now I encounter a problem when removing offline_access. Who can give me a hand? please

I use following code to get facebook authorization.

```
[facebook dialog:@"oauth" andParams:params andDelegate:self];
```

While when I extend access token with following code:

```
[facebook extendAccessTokenIfNeeded];
```

I encounter error: error_msg=The access token was not obtained using single sign-on, error_code=10

If I use following code to get authorization, I can extend access token.

```
[facebook authorize:permissions];
```

But I don't want my app directe to safari and then redirect to my app to get authorization

I see in [Removal of offline_access permission](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/), it says
Scenario 4: Client-side OAuth and Extending Access_Token Expiration Time through New Endpoint

Could I use it?

If yes, how to use it?

If no, is there any other method to extend access token? (without redirecting to safari)

```
{request_args=(

{
    key = method;
    value = "auth.extendSSOAccessToken";
},
    {
    key = sdk;
    value = ios;
},
    {
    key = "sdk_version";
    value = 2;
},
    {
    key = "access_token";
    value = AAAAAK9pJJuEBAJ5VBsWIMjfdv6s9q6bXjO4AdO3diZA6s9ABEqS1VHNG1N5ynbvxyXVrFxTZAQ4RS8vww5hFPgb86TamBD0yjqPN75xopr8ACwqu8X;
},
    {
    key = format;
    value = json;
}
), error_msg=The access token was not obtained using single sign-on, error_code=10}
```

Comment: Did you figure out this?. I'm having the same problem... and i'd really rather NOT to enable Safari auth. Thanks!

Comment: @JorgeLeandroPerez: I use Scenario 4: Client-side OAuth and Extending Access_Token Expiration Time through New Endpoint. And it works good